# How to view my virtual hosts sites without editing window etc/hosts - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, virtualhost

I have followed this tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) and have set up a virtual host: `var/www/example.com/public_html`

My host file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And I have enabled the site like so: `sudo a2ensite example.com.conf`

The tutorial suggests setting up a local hosts file which I have done on my window machine by editing `windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts` and adding the lines:

```
192.168.0.13    www.example.com
192.168.0.13    example.com
```

So I can browse to www.example.com and can see the example site. But I don't want to configure the windows hosts file for each virtual host I create. I would happily just browse to `192.168.0.13/example.com` for development purposes.

How can I achieve this?

I have tried editing `/etc/hosts/` on my server and adding the lines:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.0.1 www.example.com
```

But this made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have a name server resolve the host name to the desired IP address.

Whoever maintains your nameserver will add an entry for each of your specific domain names.  For instance example.com and www.example.com, as well as any other host name would have to have a separate entry in the name server configuration.

An example of this (in the name server zone file):
(db.example.com.zone:)

```
example.com.             IN A 50.75.184.36
www.example.com.         IN CNAME example.com.
blog.example.com.        IN CNAME example.com.
forum.example.com.       IN CNAME example.com.
```

After you have configured the DNS server you can browse the sites with any browser no different that browsing http://www.google.com.